# Arrange one object specifically behind another object?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a complex artwork in illustrator with a few hundred separate objects altogether. I want object A behind object B. I know I can send object A all the way to the back, but I would like it to be directly behind object B. If I send it back/forward one at a time, it takes an hour to get it to the right position. Is there a way I can send object A specifically behind object B?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Select the object you want to move with the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow)
- `Edit > Cut` (<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>)
- Select the object you want it behind/font of
- `Edit > Paste in Front/Back` (<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> or <kbd>b</kbd>)

The object will be pasted in the exact same position, just moved in the stacking order.

Alternatively, you can expand **layers** in the **Layers Panel** and drag layers or objects up and down.

Comment: You sir/ma'am, are the man/woman! I've always used the command-f command but never realized if i selected another object it pasted it directly in front of that one. I will say, the direct selection tool didn't do it for me, it was the regular selection tool that I needed to use, but other than that you were spot on. Thank you!

Comment: @MrRoundtree Direct Selection while holding the Option/Alt key often works better (this is actually the "Group Selection Tool"  -- it's there in the tool bar... but I've never *actually* picked it from the tool bar. Option/Alt works better :) ) If you are working *within a group* The Selection Tool won't help, which is why I mentioned the Direct Selection Tool -- and alternatively you could always enter isolation mode. Much depends upon current construction of objects.